# How to open a new window and edit it in an automated fashion?

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

Consider the following function

```
function! Exp()
    call feedkeys(":new ~/.vimrc\<CR>")
    call search('F')
endfunction
```

My expectation from Exp() was that if I call Exp() then

1) I see my vimrc file opened in a new window, and
2) the first instance of 'F' is searched in the vimrc file with the cursor landing on it.

However, what I see is that only the first expectation meets reality. In fact, the second line `call search('F')` seems to be ignored by vim.

PS: Please feel free if you have a suggestion to improve my code.

Comment: What if you replace `call feedkeys(...)` with `split $MYVIMRC`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I am sorry I do not follow. Can you elaborate on your suggestion? Also, perhaps I should have mentioned it in the question, that `.vimrc` is not really important here. I'd like to do this for arbitrary files. Thanks.

Comment: You dont need to call feedkeys to run an ex command. Just run the ex command (`split`, similar to `new`, and use `$MYVIMRC` to always get the right vimrc file)

Comment: That solves my issue. Thanks. But now I have another question. Why is `call feedkeys(":split $MYVIMRC\<CR>")` different from `split $MYVIMRC`? in the second line of the code.

Comment: Have you read `:help feedkeys()` ? It has to do with the underlying buffer of keystrokes getting manipulated, which often has unforseen impacts. Easier to just let the vimscript engine do things in order. You rarely need feedkeys.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. If you could frame your comment as an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: `Why is call feedkeys(":split $MYVIMRC\<CR>") different from split $MYVIMRC?` Because `feedkeys()` doesn't wait for the commands in the typeahead buffer to be executed, so when `search()` is invoked, your vimrc has not yet been displayed. If you had to use `feedkeys()` (you don't here), you would need to pass the `x` flag as a second argument so that `feedkeys()` waits for the keys to be processed ; you would also want the `n` flag to avoid keys from being remapped, and maybe the `t` flag to make Vim think that the keys were typed interactively by the user, and not from the rhs of a mapping.

Comment: @user938271 Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rarely need [`feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29), which does things with vim’s user input lookahead buffer and can cause weird effects.

If you just want to run an ex command, you can do so literally in vimscript (which is just ex commands):

```
new $MYVIMRC
" alternately: split $MYVIMRC
```